# Loading a self-signed P12 cert file in C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Working with certs is all still new to me.

I am trying to load a p12 cert file (I think is is called a self signed cert) for use with a channel factory. This is a C# program in VS2010 and a WFC service reference. Below are the methods I have tried and the errors I am receiving. The last bit of code is VB.net code, which runs without error. I think this indicates that the path and password to the p12 file are correct.

```
//Create the binding and channel
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

EndpointAddress serviceAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://myendpoint");
ChannelFactory<ServiceName> channelFactory = null;

channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceName>(binding, serviceAddress);


//try to add the cert - Error: Object reference not set to an instance of the object. I've tried all available X509KeyStorageFlags
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.Import(@c:\path\to\file\fw.mycert.com.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

//try to add the cert - Error: The specified network password is not correct. I've tried all available X509KeyStorageFlags
//rawCertificateData does contain 2000+ bytes
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
byte[] rawCertificateData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\path\to\file\fw.mycert.com.p12");                
channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate.Import(rawCertificateData, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

//This works in vb.net with the same path and password
Dim cert As New X509Certificate2("c:\path\to\file\fw.mycert.com.p12", "password")
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)
```

Comment: I am able to call channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate() and channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(), which work to load certs from the store.

Comment: For some stupid reason I am not able to answer my own question, but this code works     X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
    byte[] rawCertificateData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\path\to\file\fw.mycert.com.p12");
    certificate.Import(rawCertificateData, "PASSWORD", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
    channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
Sorry for the bad formatting, but I can't have carriage returns in comments. Another oddity....